# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. Exception on sending mail

Tags: c#, email, authentication

I am trying to send mails through c# code and I am getting the following exception.
`The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated`. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.This code is working fine if I use my personal `gmail smtp` settings for sending mail but when I use clients smptp settings it is giving me this exception.Application is hosted on USA server.

I dont know where I am doing wrong plz help.

```
 public static void sendBulkMail()
 {   
            DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
            SMTPBAL smtpbl = new SMTPBAL(0);
            smtpbl.LoadAll(_ds);    
            string server = _ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["SMTPX"].ToString();
            int smtpPort = WebHelper.Cast(_ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["smtpPort"].ToString(), 0);
            string From = _ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
            string User = _ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["User"].ToString();
            string Password = _ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
            string sDisclaimer = _ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["Disclaimer"].ToString();
            bool EnableSSl = WebHelper.Cast(_ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["EnableSll"], false);
            string EmailAddress = string.Empty;

            StudentBAL _stbl = new StudentBAL(0);
            _stbl.LoadAll(_ds);

            foreach (DataRow dr in _ds.Tables[_stbl.SqlEntityX].Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (dr["Email"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        if (IsValidMailAddress(dr["Email"].ToString()))
                        {
                            string Message = "Dear parent,<br/><br/> <br/> The Attendance for current course/semester of your ward," + dr["Name"].ToString() + " is available on the given below link.Please check and contact HOD in case any enquiry.<br/><br/><br/>Copy below link to your browsers address bar. <br/><br/>http://insr.MNMtechnologies.net/login/login.aspx <br/>User Name :" + dr["LoginEmailAddress"].ToString() + " / " + dr["EmailAddress"].ToString() + "<br/>Password : " + dr["Password"].ToString() + "<br/><br/><br/>Regard's<br/><br/>Institute of   management.<br/> .";
                            SMTPHelper SMTP1 = new SMTPHelper(server, smtpPort, From, Password, EnableSSl, true);
                            SMTP1.IsHTML = true;
                            SMTP1.SendEmail(From, "Institute of management", dr["Email"].ToString(), "", "", "Attendance status of your ward.", Message, false);
                        }
                    }
               }
               catch (Exception err) { }   
          }
  }
```

Comment: I don't know what is this SMTPHelper, but I suggest you visit this page: http://www.systemnetmail.com/

Comment: From past experience, I had an issue where I forgot to use credentials: `System.Net.NetworkCredential`, if it can help...

Comment: @Vince code is working fine for my personal gmail smtp. But if I use clients smtp settings I am getting this exception.That mean code is working fine.Also smtp helper is a simple class to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues some time ago, i suggest you recheck the following:

- EnableSSL true or false
- Check Credentials again
- Sometimes certain SMTP servers (mainly for companies) don't allow external access or have a separate IP for external access
- Check whether the username should include the @Host.com or without it

I hope one of them works for you.